# Filemaker - Find/Search by summary field?

Tags: filemaker

So I've basically completed my entire Filemaker Solution, and am now just adding some extra features to polish it up for professional performance. I've added a number of charts and summary fields with no problem. The issue I'm having now however, is that I'm trying to add a drop field to allow the user to select from a top percentage of a particular summarized data field.

Basically, I have a bunch of records with a field for the 'time spent' on a particular project attached to them. I summarized this 'time spent' field into a field called 'total hours'. I charted the data of 'total hours' among the different records based on the affiliate they each worked on (each record worked on 1 of 20 affiliates, so a lot of similar affiliates to sum up). Up until now, no problem. Now I want to add this drop down field to allow the user to select only the top 5%, for example, of the hours spent TOTAL (not just on one individual affiliate). The calculations and conditional statements I have are absolutely correct, but the problem I am having is that Filemaker wont allow searching/finding a range of values for a summary field (ie. set field ['total hours'] -- ['begin time' & "..." & 'end time'] ) becuase you can not set/change the value of a summary field

Comment: ...of a summary field, even in find mode. I've tried a number of different approaches from changing charting calculations, to individually looping through records and omitting unnecessary fields, with no luck.

If anyone has any insight on how I might go about this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Summary fields summarize the found set. They cannot be searched, because that would make the found set depend on the result of the summary field - which in turns depends on the found set. I did not understand what exactly you want, but in general, if you want to show only groups whose sub-summary value meets some criteria, you must loop among the groups and omit those that don't.